# How to decide what to use [Sqlite, Realm, CoreData, User-default, JSON file] to store data iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, database, optimization, local-storage

After searching everywhere I found there is no properer comparison between SQLite, Realm, CoreData, UserDefaults, and JSON file.

You can find pros and cons easily but it's hard to know what to use.

I know the decision is totally dependent on the requirements. But still there must be a way to make decision.

Assuming the following cases, which options are best for individual and why?

1. Saving user watched history [Huge amount of data, Only insert, and delete operation]
2. Saving contact numbers [Max 1000 numbers, Need fast fetch, and continuous operation]
3. Saving simple GET API request [Use for caching]

Note: I am not talking about storing sensitive information here.

Feel free to add/update more relevant cases.

Comment: I would go with CoreData, it is easy, quick and native.

Comment: I think one of the main requirement you should consider is data migration & versioning like adding new properties to history object Core data & Realm will handle it easier than doing it manually using JSON Codable as an example.

Comment: you can go with SQLite to store large amount of data no issue at all, use vacuum to reduce size, indexing, easy migration, you can save JSON etc... i manage same around 50 mb file size. strong knowledge of query required.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The most part of data storage implementation is just SQLite wrappers. The most common iOS implementations are SQLite, ORM, CoreData, Realm, Keychain.

Another part of implementations is just a simple text. For example, UserDefaults is just an XML file which you can edit using simple iOS API. But SQLite wrappers are more useful for performance reasons when you work with more than dozens of elements.

So, what about SQLite wrappers?

1. You can use [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) but it has several disadvantages: this is not a thread-safe, you can obtain the data only at allowed moments of application, from time to time it returns incorrect results for existed elements. This is useful for passwords, no more.
2. [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) has native API, but it has got memory leaks disadvantages, complicated API, this is not a thread-safe database, not a good performance.
3. [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/whyc.html). First of all, you can use the native C library with 11KB dependency. Disadvantages: Old-style C API, raw SQL queries.
4. [SQLite Swift wrapper](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift). In this case, you have to use third-party libraries. But well perform.
5. [Realm](http://sharkorm.com/). This is really well-performed and easy to use. But it has got a disadvantage for thread-safe. The difference between ORM and Realm is that the objects in the Realm are not stored as an obvious table, it has its own magic how to convert the data into table representation.
6. [Firebase database](https://realm.io/). I didn't use this library in the production. It has got online implementation as a primary feature. I'm not sure is it correct using a primary internal database.

What about the summary?

SQLite (Wrapper, pure C) and Realm in our test have nearly the same performance. CoreData isn't good enough.

SQLite wrapper and Realm have enough good API.

The only SQLite wrapper is really thread-safe.

Comment: Realm is not a SQLite wrapper

Comment: @IanNewson Realm saves its data to SQLite database. I can agree with you. But actually this is a database which maps its data to SQLite table fields.

Comment: No sorry: "JP explains the principles behind its design that make it so fast and efficient, as well as the reasons for writing it on our own as opposed to wrapping SQLite" from https://academy.realm.io/posts/jp-simard-realm-core-database-engine/

Comment: @IanNewson this is not actually 'much faster'. And Realm is really bad in multithreading cases. Sorry. I really disappointed when tested this framework.

Comment: Hi, I've made many systems with it. Regardless, I was only responding to the sqlite wrapper assertion.

Comment: Core Data can be used in a multi-threaded environment with different NSManagedObjectContexts

Answer (score 7):

Available Options to save data in iOS.

**User Default:** Quicky persists a small amount of data.

**Codable (NSCoder):** for saving the custom object.

**Keychain:** Small bit of data securely.

**SQLite:** Persist large data but require query operation.

**Core Data:** Object-Oriented Database.

**Realm:** Faster and easier database solution.

**CoreData, Sqlite & Realm store plain text in-store if you don't tell it to encrypt, you can use encryption in all to make it secure.**

- **Saving user-watched history [Huge amount of data, Only insert, and delete operation]** Coredata & Realm should be used.
- **Saving contact numbers [Max 1000 numbers, Need fast fetch, and continuous operation]** Coredata & Realm should be used.
- **Saving simple GET API request [Use for caching]** Codable, Coredata & Realm should be used. The response can be used for
     offline storage.

Answer (score 5):

Data storage and caching very important topic. Choosing way to store data can rely on whole app design.

### Caching:

**NSURLCache:** Simple option to configure cache of desired size. Works good for caching data that does not need any post processing (JSON, Image Requests).

```swift
let URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 4 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(URLCache)
```

**File Cache:** If you need to post process data somehow (like round corners on images, build own data structure from JSON) file cache can be an option. Images can be saved as plain files, for data objects you can use `NSCoding` protocol.

**Database:** For fully working offline mode better to use database.

### Persistence:

**NSUserDefaults:** Small pieces of data. Not secure, no sync.

**SQLite:** Memory efficient and cross-platform. Usually not a best option. Useful when you want to share existed cross-platform database in app.

**Core Data:** Good option when you need complex queries and complex relations between objects. Have basic migration support and visual code editor (with code generator). Probably it should be default option unless you need: syncing or cross-platform.

**YapDatabase:** Faster than CoreData. Have iCloud sync.

**Realm:** Some article says that it is faster than CoreData and thread safe. Have a lot of options and some of them are paid (like Sync). May be a good alternative for CoreData.

**Firebase:** Cloud platform. Have offline mode, but paid.

**CouchBase:** Free Sync. No migrations needed as very flexible schema.

### In a conclusion:

Simple records: **UserDefaults**, **NSCoding**
Local data storage, complicated records: **CoreData** (**Yap**, **Realm**)
Syncronization: **CouchDB**, **Yap** (iCloud), **CoreData** (iCloud-), **Realm** (Paid), **Firebase** (Paid)
Speed: **Yap**, **Realm**
Patform or Cloud Based: **Firebase**, **Parse**
Cross-platform: **Realm**, **CouchDB**, **MongoDB**, **Firebase**

Answer (score 4):

My personal opinion is the following:

- **Core Data**: Good support from Apple, native, visual editor, good performance for most of the use cases, but with a quite uncomfortable API in my opinion.
- **Realm**: Simple API, incredible speed, easy migrations. But personally, the issue of threads bothers me a lot. Working with threads using Realm is difficult and annoying. For the rest, it seems great to me. Another thing, it also adds some size to the APP but it's worth it.

If you ask me personally, I love realm, I've also used Core Data a lot, but ended up sticking with Realm.